# Map with soft values in Eclipse Collections

Tags: java, eclipse-collections

I am currently looking at consolidating to a single collections library in a project I'm involved in, and though I have little experience with it, I really like the look of Eclipse Collections.

One concrete use case we have is that we use a `Map` implementation with soft value references in several places as a simple cache. We currently use Apache Commons Collections' `ReferenceMap` for this purpose, for example:

```
private final Map<Integer, Long[]> cache = new ReferenceMap<>();
```

Of course this can be replaced by a standard Java `HashMap` where the value is an `SoftReference` implementation, but I was hoping Eclipse Collections had a similar "convenience" collection type or factory/builder for this purpose. Is there such a thing? Or perhaps more broadly formulated: how would I set up a Map with soft value references using Eclipse Collections and a minimum amount of boilerplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse Collections does not currently have a `WeakValueHashMap` or `SoftValueHashMap`. I also can't think off hand of a way of setting one up with minimal boiler plate without implementing them. If you want to use the Eclipse Collections `MutableMap` API instead of `Map`, you can adapt the `ReferenceMap` above.

```
private final MutableMap<Integer, Long[]> cache = Maps.adapt(new ReferenceMap<>());
```

This won't help you get rid of the Apache Commons dependency, but gets you a step closer to a consistent API usage.

If you are interested in contributing to Eclipse Collections, there is certainly room for `WeakValueHashMap` and `SoftValueHashMap` implementations.